# Unregister DelegateCommand / Get A list of DelegateCommands Used

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates

It think its possible to unregister a `DelegateCommand` but how? I didn't find any useful examples when googling.

And my 2nd question is it possible to retrieve a complete list of events/delegate commands that are used by an application?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unregister by `-=` such:

```
myEvent += (MyDelegateHandler)myDelegateFunction;
```

and unregister:

```
myEvent -= (MyDelegateHandler)myDelegateFunction;
```

You can enumerate all delegates via GetInvocationList

```
foreach(Delegate d in myEvent.GetInvocationList())
{
    myEvent -= (MyDelegateHandler)d;
}
```

Comment: That is a good answer but still what i`m trying to do is to access this delegate command from another class and unregister it there, so i dont know currently how can i access it.